# xscreensaver doesn't run on one of two vnc sessions

Tags: linux, vnc, xscreensaver

Can anyone help identify the problem and solution to this:

I have a linux box on which I have two vncserver sessions running. They were spawned as follows:

```
> vncserver :1
New 'hostname:1 (user)' desktop is hostname:1

Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/user/.vnc/hostname:1.log

> vncserver :2
New 'hostname:2 (user)' desktop is hostname:2

Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/user/.vnc/hostname:2.log
```

**The problem/question**:

`xscreensaver` does not seem to run in the second VNC desktop, but does run in the first.

After the timeout period in the second vnc session, the screen blacks out, and no screensavers launch.

I'd like to understand why xscreensaver does not run on the second vnc session, and if it can be made to do so.

**What I have tried**:

- I read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440528/xscreensaver-to-load-at-startup) and confirmed that my `/etc/xdg/autostart/screensaver.desktop` is as described.
- Verified that `$DISPLAY` is `:1` and `:2` in the respective vnc sessions.
- Manually initiated `xscreensaver` in the second vnc session, e.g. by running `xscreensaver-command -next` and verified that screensavers are displayed.
- Ran `xscreensaver-command -restart` -- this had no effect on the described situation as far as I could tell.
- Observed that xscreensaver simultaneously runs on the monitor that is physically connected to my linux box as well as vnc session 1 (but not on vnc session 2)
- `cat`'ed my `/var/log/messages` and found many instances of the following text -- are these relevant?

.

```
Mar  7 13:45:28 localhost gnome-session: xscreensaver: 13:45:28: couldn't grab pointer!  (AlreadyGrabbed)
Mar  7 13:45:28 localhost gnome-session: xscreensaver: 13:45:28: unable to grab keyboard or mouse!  Blanking aborted.
Mar  7 13:46:32 localhost gnome-session: xscreensaver: 13:46:32: couldn't grab keyboard!  (AlreadyGrabbed)
```

**My distro**:

```
>cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013
```